# "API rate limit exceeded" when trying to install local R package using devtools::install()

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

Package development beginner here!

I'm trying to turn some code into a local R package for the very first time. I made a package using `usethis::create_package()`, added documentation using `devtools::document()`.

Now, after playing around with it for a while, I ran into the following error when trying to install the newest version using `devtools::install()`:

```
Error: HTTP error 403.
  API rate limit exceeded for [my IP]. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)

  Rate limit remaining: 0/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2019-03-18 16:32:05 UTC

  To increase your GitHub API rate limit
  - Use `usethis::browse_github_pat()` to create a Personal Access Token.
  - Use `usethis::edit_r_environ()` and add the token as `GITHUB_PAT`.
```

The problem *still* exists if I use `devtools:install_local("my_folder_name")`. What genuinely confuses me here is that I am hitting a GitHub rate limit by trying to install a package sitting in a local folder.

Did I make a mistake in the package setup, or does using `devtools::install()` always involve the GitHub API? 
Is there anything I can change to keep the installation process of my package local and thus avoid the rate limit issue?

**Edit:** My DESCRIPTION file refers to other packages:

```
Depends: 
    R (>= 3.4.3),
    dplyr
Imports:
    RMariaDB,
    dbplyr,
    DBI,
    reshape2,
    RColorBrewer,
    knitr,
    kableExtra,
    scales,
    magrittr,
    DT,
    formattable,
    testthat,
    ggplot2,
    rmarkdown
```

Comment: do you have dependencies? can you maybe show the `DESCRIPTION` file of your package?

Comment: and you don't have anything under `Remotes:`, correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's right, nothing under Remotes.

Comment: @RolandASc Thanks a lot for the pointer, it seems like the default dependencies behaviour of `install()` was in fact the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that by default, `devtools::install()` checks for all packages listed as dependencies under `Depends`, `Imports` and `LinkingTo` in the `DESCRIPTION` file (see explanation of `dependencies = NA` option in devtools reference manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/devtools.pdf)). This is also true for `remotes::install_local()`, which `devtools::install_local()` links to.

A solution to this is to explicitly disable checking package dependencies: If you use `devtools::install("my_local_package", dependencies = FALSE)` instead, you no longer need to connect to `api.github.com`. Doing this makes sense when you know you already have the necessary dependencies installed, which is the case when you're R-packaging your own code.

(Also worth noting: The default options in `devtools::install()` require an internet connection for installation of any packages but by setting `dependencies = FALSE`, it's also possible to install a local package offline!)