# install_github results in an api rate limit error regardless of which package is installed

Tags: r, github

`install_github` results in an api rate limit error regardless of which package is installed. Here is the error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 403.
  API rate limit exceeded for 206.214.41.90. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)

  Rate limit remaining: 0/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2019-09-20 17:45:53 UTC

  To increase your GitHub API rate limit
  - Use `usethis::browse_github_pat()` to create a Personal Access Token.
  - Use `usethis::edit_r_environ()` and add the token as `GITHUB_PAT`.
```

This post touches on my issue but I'm not installing from a local source so the solution wont work (["API rate limit exceeded" when trying to install local R package using devtools::install()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225847/api-rate-limit-exceeded-when-trying-to-install-local-r-package-using-devtools)).

And just to be clear, I haven't accessed github in anyway from my internet connection in months. Whats the source of the error and does anyone know of a way to install packages from github that doesnt rely on a request via their api?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Seems like a question for GitHub support to answer the question of "why API-limited if *I haven't accessed github in anyway ... in months*". The mention of `'unknown package'` seems weird to me, but since you didn't include your command line, we can't see what repo you're attempting to install from, and what other arguments you're using (such as `dependencies=FALSE`).

Comment: Like I said, its all repos, all packages....

Comment: Are other users,scripts, etc also making unauthenticated requests on that IP as well. given the error suggests using a PAT, have you considered switching to that?

Comment: See [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).